# Restore database postgres pgadmin4

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a problem restoring a database backup in pgadmin4.

The database I want to restore is created with pgadmin3.

Here is the error message that it is displayed:

> Restore failed.
>   ascii codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0 ordinal not range(128)

I use pgadmin 9.6.

Comment: Use pgAdmin4 v.1.3, It has fixes related to backup/restore.