# How to fix "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 187667: invalid start byte"

Tags: postgresql

I'm opening pgAdmin 4 (version 10.8 of postgres) and this error is appearing:

> {"success":0,"errormsg":"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 187667: invalid start byte","info":"","result":null,"data":null}

Image:

[image: error print]

Comment: Please add the JSON error as text, not as an image.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit. So, I would suggest doing a search engine search for "pgAdmin codec can't decode byte in position" and seeing what you get.

Comment: What version of pgAdmin are you using (please edit that into your question as well)? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156442/restore-database-postgres-pgadmin4) has a comment to say that upgrading might help.

Comment: I'm using pgAdmin 4 and version 10 of postgres

Comment: Which version exactly, down to the patch release? The number will usually be in the form `x.y.z`.

Comment: Also (separate question to answer as well) are you using the very latest version?

Comment: I'm using a 10.8

Comment: Sorry, what exact patch version of pgAdmin? The number will usually be in the form `x.y.z`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there is some non-ascii character in the dictionary and it can't be encoded/decoded. One simple way to avoid this error is to encode such strings with encode() function as follows (if a is the string with non-ascii character):

```
a.encode('utf-8').strip()
```